# Bootstrap grid system classes does not apply its changes on screen size change

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

When I change the screen size using a browser's Device Toolbar, the Bootstrap Grid System classes (col-lg-12, col-md-6, etc.) are not applied. I need to refresh the page for it to take effect.
What could be the reason behind this?
How can to solve?

**Techs:** Angular, Bootstrap

**Browsers tried in:** Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Firefox

Comment: Generally it works when you change the size from dev tools. Could you mention the angular and bootstrap version that you are using?

Comment: I need to refresh the page to make it work (to apply the styles). Angular 9, bootstrap 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have below tags in Index.html under `<head>` tag

```
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```